enum "DATA" not found error
I'm making an addon which does the following operations with curves:

Automatically adds Curve object
Sets DATA property tab active (to show curve's Resolution settings)

Both things should've been managed by this fragment of code:
import bpy

#1
bpy.ops.curve.primitive_bezier_circle_add()

#2
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'PROPERTIES':
        area.spaces[0].context ='DATA'
        break


If I separately run #1 and later run #2 it works perfectly.
BUT when it's being executed as a consecutive code - the error emerges:
TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: enum "DATA" not found in ('TOOL', 'RENDER', 'OUTPUT', 'VIEW_LAYER', 'SCENE', 'WORLD', 'TEXTURE')


Note that "DATA" property tab exists, when some object is active and doesn't exist, if there is no active object.
Evidently, #2 section of code tries to access Blender's ui while ui's behaving like there is no active object. Which is strange, since after #1 section - active object already exists.
To me it seems, like Blender updates its state not as fast as code works.
Hence I tried to put sleep() between #1 and #2. -> It has not helped.

Two questions:

What causes this error ?

How can I bypass this error ?




Hello, maybe delay execution of the second part of your script with an application timer https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html a few milliseconds should do

For performance reasons, the internal UI code will be updated once in redraw level until the script ends. (Imagine if the UI code was updated immediately every time an object was added, this would result in poor performance if a large number of objects were added.)
Therefore, after adding an object, the ui state remains in the old state causing the script to fail.
Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a good feature for refreshing the UI immediately, so you'll need to find a way to delay running the code.
Here is an operator method Example can bypass this error
import bpy

class UpdateUiAfter(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.update_ui_after"
    bl_label = "Update UI After"
    bl_options = {"INTERNAL"}
    
    fn_ui_update_after = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        bpy.context.area.tag_redraw()
        UpdateUiAfter.fn_ui_update_after()
        return {'CANCELLED'}

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


bpy.utils.register_class(UpdateUiAfter)



def run_fn_ui_after(fn_ui_update_after):
    UpdateUiAfter.fn_ui_update_after = fn_ui_update_after
    bpy.ops.wm.update_ui_after()


def fn_ui_update_after():
    #2
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'PROPERTIES':
            space = area.spaces[0]
            space.show_region_header = space.show_region_header
            area.spaces[0].context ='DATA'
            break
    

bpy.ops.curve.primitive_bezier_circle_add()
run_fn_ui_after(fn_ui_update_after)




Both solutions: yours and one suggested by Gorgious do the thing. But I would prefer to avoid any kind of hardcoded delays, since they could be not long enough or oppositely too long - depending on the user's hardware. So if we cannot force the redraw - may be we could WAIT for it ? Is there any way to trace that redraw has happened ?

I'd like to know too if possible. update() function and tag_redraw() in the API will not immediately updates the UI.

I updated the answer so it works without a timer and should be more safety.

XY - The new version of your answer is a pure perfection. You are a wizard :)
